# CodeIgniter + Tank Auth. How to log user time, sign in, etc

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, tankauth

I was hoping someone could clearly explain an easy way of logging the time of a user when they are signed into my website. I want to be able to log this time and then display it for an administrator to view.

Thanks in advance,

Filipe

Answer (score 2):

You could combine the users table with ci_sessions table to access the user_agent, ip_address and last_activity columns (last_activity is a timestamp, so use with from_unixtime(last_activity)  to get even more info for the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Tank_auth created user table should have a last_login column.  You can query that to get the login times.